# Creating interactive pattern with Konva

Tags: javascript, canvas, konva, vue-konva

I got the following [`canvas`](https://codepen.io/dcode-software/pen/yLvWNpx). Pixels should be clickable, with changeable color. I need to implement this canvas using [vue-konva](https://github.com/konvajs/vue-konva) library, because I want to add zoom (scaling) and other features. The problem is that I can't define each pixel as a separate shape, because my canvas can be bigger than 100x100 pixels and I'm afraid this can be harmful for performance. I didn't find any tutorials for building a pattern with konva in Internet. Don't you know how to implement this canvas?